# MySQL query slows page load on external server

Tags: mysql

The following query adversely affects page load when uploaded to my external server:

```
SELECT 
   compositions.composer, compositions.composition, compositions.date, compositions.performedBy
FROM 
   compositions
   INNER JOIN
   (SELECT composer 
    FROM compositions  
    WHERE 
      composer IN (
         SELECT composer FROM compositions 
         GROUP BY composer 
         HAVING COUNT(1) < 15
      )
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1) AS RandComposer
ON 
   compositions.composer = RandComposer.composer
ORDER BY compositions.composition
```

Total page load time is in excess of 4 seconds, with the bulk of this due to the wait time for the PHP page containing the query ([see Pingdom screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjnwgpfjnss81tj/Pingdom.png?dl=0)).

All relevant fields in the table 'compositions' are indexed ([see phpMyAdmin screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0fjmowhoahbivik/phpMyAdmin.png?dl=0)).

I can also provide the output from EXPLAIN in phpMyAdmin, but I do not have sufficient reputation to post a third link.

I would be most appreciative if someone could take a look at the query and advise how it might be improved to reduce page-load time.

Answer (score 0):

Recasting the query solved the problem. The following code loads without delay.

```
SELECT 
compositions.composer, compositions.composition, 
compositions.date, compositions.performedBy
FROM 
    compositions 
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT composer FROM compositions 
        GROUP BY composer 
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 15
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS RandComposer
ON 
    compositions.composer = RandComposer.composer
ORDER BY 
    compositions.composition;
```